# Bike mounted camera bag

Tags: bags, camera

Are there any bike mounted bags for a camera, that could *safely* hold my Sony NEX-5? I'd be happy enough if the camera fitted in with the 16mm pancake lens (as most of the shots are landscapes anyway). However, I was only able to find bags for cell phones or very slim compact cameras.

The camera dimensions without lens are per spec `111x59x38` mm (WxHxD); my own measurements give cca `114x63x39` mm. With the lens mounted the depth is about 62mm and the height just slightly bigger.

[Sony NEX-5 with 16mm pancake http://a.img-dpreview.com/reviews/SonyNex5Nex3/Images/NEX-5_with_16mm-001.jpg](http://a.img-dpreview.com/reviews/SonyNex5Nex3/Images/NEX-5_with_16mm-001.jpg)
[full size photo](http://a.img-dpreview.com/reviews/SonyNex5Nex3/Images/NEX-5_with_16mm.jpg)

Here's a top photo to get the idea of the thickness: [link](http://www.photoreview.com.au/reviews/advanced/NEX-5_16mm-F2.jpg).

I'd like a bag that I could mount on the handlebar, allowing a quick access without having to step off the bike for a quick shot.

Or are there some solutions I could modify to my needs (more or less easily)?

I'm open to your suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ortlieb used to make two camera-specific bags that you could probably keep inside their handlebar bag, the [Aqua Zoom](https://www.ortlieb.com/en/Aqua-Zoom/) and the Aqua Zoom Plus. These are now discontinued but you can still find them for sale.

However, the [Ortlieb Ultimate](https://www.ortlieb.com/en/lenkertaschen/) is a great handlebar bag that snaps on and off the handlebars, and also has a [camera insert](https://www.ortlieb.com/en/Ultimate2-6%20Camera%20Insert/?produkt=ultimate_camerainsert&parent=ultimate6_proe). I highly recommend the Ultimate, although the mounting is a little tricky to install.

Comment: I don't really understand how could I attach the Aqua bags on my handlebar. Even though the closure system on the Aqua Zoom model looks great!

Comment: The Ultimate bags seem pretty large for my needs, however, I've found a nice [manual on their site](http://ortlieb.de/_anleit/ultimate5.pdf) showing the smaller [Ultimate5 Compact](http://ortlieb.de/_pdf_en/ultimate5compact.pdf) that might work, just not sure about the Velcro flap...

Comment: As a bonus, the Ultimate works with Klickfix mounts, which are less expensive and [easier to attach](http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/reviews/board/message/?o=RrzLF&thread_id=134940&v=2q&page=1&nested=0) than the Ortlieb mounts, but not quite as slick to use. I assume the compact uses the same mount.

Comment: @Czechnology - What kind of bar setup do you have? I know that mounting large handlebars on, say, small drop bars can be a problem. Are there cables in the way?

Comment: I'll add a photo when I get back to my dorm. There are some cables in the front (both brakes and both gear shifters) but shouldn't be a problem for a _smaller_ bag.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Mountain FeedBag would do the trick.  It's made for holding food but it's padded with a soft interior and should safely hold your camera.  It mounts in the corner between your stem and handlebar, you can easily access it while riding.

http://www.epicrideresearch.com/product-information.php

---

*Update as of May 2011*

The **Mountain Feed Bag** (designed by [*Epic Ride Research*](http://www.epicrideresearch.com/)) has been [acquired](http://xxcmag.com/?p=1431) by [*Revelate Designs LLC.*](http://www.revelatedesigns.com/).
(It seems that the founder of *ERR* had [some health problems](http://xxcmagblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/mountain-feedbag-update.html). Hopefully she's well again.)

Do your shopping through them, as the ERR site doesn't seem responsive and also had some trouble with international shipping, from what I've read.

Comment: That looks pretty nice but is it waterproof in case of rain? It doesn't seem that way.

Comment: But it seems like an awesome bike accessory, I might get it for that :)

Comment: It's water resistant for sure, but not waterproof.  It will protect your camera when splashing through puddles, but in a downpour it would get pretty wet.